# MS Word 2019: Limit text boundaries display to margins (exclude paragraphs)?

Tags: microsoft-word, display-settings, microsoft-word-2019

In Word 2019, when you enable "Display text boundaries," the result shows margin boundaries (desirable) but also lines between paragraphs (not desirable). Is there a way to limit the display to only the margins?

Note: It's an awkward workaround, but if no alternative, then I could temporarily put a faint border at the margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that you really need to put a faint border (Such as the border of tables or text boxes) at the margins as a workaround.

Not like Office 2010 or earlier versions, Word 2019 shows the boundaries around each paragraphs instead of the pages. It is by design.

Suzanne S. Barnhill (the MVP of Office) has shared an idea in Word UserVoice forum, it gained the support of many users.

[**Bring back "classic" text boundaries**](https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9253599-bring-back-classic-text-boundaries)

But so far, Microsoft has not brought it back in the new version of Office.

Comment: Is there an error in your comment (i.e., MS has NOT brought it back?).  Also, good pointer to the link to cast a vote. I just did (no signup required). To anyone else reading this thread, if you cast a vote at the link that Emily posted, then consider being specific the text boundaries are important to you. Maybe it will help push the matter better than mere complaints.

Comment: @RJo Sorry for that, I modify it (add "not").